# IEEE-754 to Float in C

Tags: c, floating-point, converters, ieee-754

I have viewed many similar questions and I have yet to find a solution. Currently, -1.978569 is the output instead of -7.9142766. I am trying to match the output of this page: http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html

Thank you for your time!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float IEEE_754_to_Float(const unsigned char b[4]) {
        int sign = (b[0] >> 7) ? -1 : 1;

        unsigned int fraction_bits = ((b[1] & 0x7F) << 16) + (b[2] << 8) + b[3];

        float fraction = 0.5f;
        unsigned char ii;
        for (ii = 0; ii < 24; ++ii)
                fraction += ldexpf((fraction_bits >> (23 - ii)) & 1, -(ii + 1));

        float significand = sign * fraction;

        return ldexpf(significand, 1);
}

int main() {
    unsigned char b[]={0xC0, 0xFD, 0x41, 0xC1};
    float f=IEEE_754_to_Float(b);
    printf("%f\n",f);
    return(0); }
```

Comment: Your program doesn't use the exponent part of the floating point number anywhere - that's probably a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Good first question!

Comment: My exponent-calculating code was wrong, so it was returning -inf and inf. That is why I removed it. The other code on this page works. Thanks! Thanks for the warm welcome, John!

Comment: why don't use `union { unsigned char b[4]; float f }` or just `memcpy(&f, b, sizeof(f))`

Answer (score 2):

You have a few errors.

First, you're ignoring the exponent field.  Those are in bits 30-23:

```
int exponentField = ((b[0] & 0x7F) << 1) + (b[1] >> 7);
```

Second, there's a leading 1 assumed with the significant.  (Also, there are only 23 significand bits, so your loop should really only go up to 23, but since you're just adding 0 it doesn't matter too much.)  If you change the loop to the following:

```
float fraction = 1.0f;
unsigned char ii;
for (ii = 0; ii < 24; ++ii)
    fraction += ldexpf((fraction_bits >> (23 - ii)) & 1, -ii);
```

it should be fine.

Lastly, you'll need to account for the exponent, which is calculated from `exponentField`:

```
return ldexpf(significand, exponentField - 127);
```

Comment: +1, but the change to `1.0f` has to be accompanied by a fix in the loop, too.  The exponent should just be `-ii`, rather than `-(ii + 1)`, right?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it, and it works (via codepad.org).  Good catch.  I still have to convince myself why that is, though: first time around aren't you wanting to add to the first place to the right of the decimal?  ldexpf(1, 0) is 1, not 0.5 (0.1 in binary), right?  (Thanks for the ++)

Comment: Edited my response based on Carl Norum's catch.

Comment: @John, on closer inspection it's the loop indices - they should actually only go 0-22 and the subtraction should be `22 - ii`.  There are 23 bits of mantissa, not 24.  I guess that would be a better fix than the exponent change I suggested.  As it stands, the first time through the loop just adds 0 every time.

Answer (score 1):

Exponent bits are 129, offset by 127 = 2.  -1.978569 * (2 ** 2) = -7.9142766.

Comment: ++.  I'm still a little puzzled why he got so close to 1/4 of the correct answer.  He started his significand at 0.5, not 1.0.

Comment: Looks like offsetting errors: his original code looped over 24 bits of mantissa instead of 23. The first time through the loop, it picked up the LSB of the exponent, which is a 1, and added `ldexp(1.0, -1)`, which happens to be 0.5.